# adding pdf text stream with right justification, how?

Tags: pdf, text

I want to add right justified text to a pdf. currently for left justify it's like this:-

```
m_Radians = angle * 3.14/180;
float f1 = cos(m_Radians),  f2 = sin(m_Radians), 
      f3 = -sin(m_Radians), f4 = cos(m_Radians);
```

for right justify I can do it like this but then the text is right justified OK but the text is mirror'ed.

```
f1 = -cos(m_Radians),  f2 = sin(m_Radians), 
      f3 = -sin(m_Radians), f4 = cos(m_Radians);


sprintf(ss, "\nQ\nBT\n/%s gs\n%f %f %f %f %f %f Tm\n%s\n/%s %d Tf\n(%s) Tj\nET\n",
        m_ExtGStateName,
        f1,f2,f3,f4,
        m_aPos[0], m_aPos[1], 
        MakeColor().c_str(),
        m_FontName,
        m_Parameters.size, 
        m_Text.c_str());
```

any ideas how to achieve it?

in acrobat sdk ASFixedMatrix is used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible the way you are trying to do this. PDF contains no text operators or other capabilities to automatically generate right-aligned text.

The only thing you can do is calculate the width of the text you want to place and then use the regular matrix, text matrix or text placement operators to position that text so that for each line the end point is the same.